# What are the consequences of disabling the analytics index?

Tags: reporting, indexing

If I were to delete the data from the analytics index, and then disable the observables declared in the in the crawlers defined here,

#### *Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Analytics.config*

```xml
<index id="sitecore_analytics_index" ...>
  ...
  <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsVisitCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Visit Crawler</CrawlerName>
      <ObservableName>VisitAggregationObservable</ObservableName>
      ...
    </crawler>
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsVisitPageCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Visit Page Crawler</CrawlerName>
      <ObservableName>VisitPageAggregationObservable</ObservableName>
      ...
    </crawler>
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsVisitPageEventCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Visit Page Event Crawler</CrawlerName>
      <ObservableName>VisitPageEventAggregationObservable</ObservableName>
      ...
    </crawler>
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsContactCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Contact Crawler</CrawlerName>
      ...
      <observables hint="list:AddObservable">
        <observable>ContactAggregationObservable</observable>
        <observable>ContactChangeObservable</observable>
      </observables>
    </crawler>
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsContactTagCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Contact Tag Crawler</CrawlerName>
      ...
      <observables hint="list:AddObservable">
        <observable>ContactTagAggregationObservable</observable>
        <observable>ContactTagChangeObservable</observable>
      </observables>
    </crawler>
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers.AnalyticsAddressCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics">
      <CrawlerName>Lucene Address Tag Crawler</CrawlerName>
      ...
      <observables hint="list:AddObservable">
        <observable>AddressAggregationObservable</observable>
        <observable>AddressChangeObservable</observable>
      </observables>
    </crawler>
  </locations>
```

what functionality would be affected in Sitecore?  My understanding is it would only affect reporting and not the actual collection of the analytics data, as that is all collected into the XDB.

If, after doing this, I re-enabled the observables and initiated a rebuild of the Reporting Database, would we get this data back in the analytics index and the reports would be available again?

Comment: playing with fire, Chris!  But I concur that the search index plays a role in data retrieval not collection.

Comment: did you tried this? if yes, is there any effect on CD instance when you disable/remove this index from CD ?

Answer (score 2):

Content delivery should be unaffected, as you stated, unless you're doing something custom and accessing analytics data from front-end code. Reporting could be extremely slow, depending on the quantity of data in your DB.

Indexes are generally disposable; they aren't the canonical source of any data. Once you rebuild the index as you describe, the index should be accurately updated for whatever data is in the DB.

This post by Adam Conn supports the ability to rebuild the analytics index without losing data: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/rebuilding-the-sitecore-analytics-index

Comment: What's the reason for reporting to slow down? And by the way, the analytics index is rebuilt every time you rebuild the reporting database.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: I may be wrong (and I haven't tested this), but if you remove the index, that's going to make any sort of querying slow.